# Is there a way to get a user input in a textbox using Windows Application using C# and pass the input value to a cmd file?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, cmd

Is there a way to get a user input in a textbox using Windows Application using C# and pass the input value to a cmd file? I don’t want to let end user navigate to a cmd file from application rather simply get the values and pass the input parameters  to cmd file within application. 
For Example – 2 Text-boxes to get a 'Server Name' and 'Project Name'. Pass the values to a cmd file wherever required.

Comment: Yes there is. But couldn't you just use `set /p ServerName=Enter Server Name:` to prompt for input

Comment: Thanks but I have have multiple parameters to pass in cmd file. All parameters will getting collected via windows application controls so this is one reason i don't wan't to prompt for user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your winforms app produce a file of environment variables to load.

1. Create your winforms application `PromptForInputs.exe`
2. Add a form with your text boxes and a submit button.
3. Add a submit handler containing code like:

   ```
       string outputFile = "__inputs__.cmd";
       System.IO.File.Delete(outputFile);
       System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(outputFile, new string[] {
           "SET ServerName=" + TextBoxServerName.Text,
           "SET Blah=" + TextBoxBlah.Text 
       });
   ```
4. In your cmd file:

   ```
   PromptForInputs.exe
   call __inputs__.cmd
   echo %ServerName%
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much.. got some idea to proceed. will let you know the outcome.